Get result from Eval gnome dbus API method
I'm using the Eval method from the gnome dbus API to get the name of the window that is currently in focus. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/data/dbus-interfaces/org.gnome.Shell.xml#L3
The code below runs without errors (but with critical messages), but how do I get the result? The Eval method has 2 out parameters: success or not and the result. As I understand it, they are returned in GVariant form from the g_dbus_proxy_call_sync method. How can I get data from this GVariant? I tried to retrieve the data using g_variant_get but had no success. It's not entirely clear how to use it.
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>


void test_getwindows(GDBusProxy *proxy)
{
   GError *error = NULL;
   g_printf("Calling Eval()...\n");
   GVariant *result = g_dbus_proxy_call_sync(proxy,
           "Eval",
           g_variant_new("s", "global.get_window_actors().find(actor =>     actor.meta_window.has_focus()).meta_window.get_title()"),
           G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
           -1,
           NULL,
           &error);
   g_assert_no_error(error);

   // Here I need to get the result, 2 out parameters
   gboolean success;
   gchar *window_title;
   g_variant_get(result, "(bs)", &success, &window_title);
   g_printf("window_title: %s\nsuccess: %d\n", window_title, success);
}

int main(void)
{
   GDBusProxy *proxy;
   GDBusConnection *conn;
   GError *error = NULL;

   conn = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION, NULL, &error);
   g_assert_no_error(error);

   proxy = g_dbus_proxy_new_sync(conn,
              G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_NONE,
              NULL,
              "org.gnome.Shell", 
              "/org/gnome/Shell/",
              "org.gnome.Shell",
              NULL,
              &error);
   g_assert_no_error(error);

   test_getwindows(proxy);
   return 0;
}

Result of running the code:
(process:4308): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:02:57.280: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
Calling Eval()...
(process:4308): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 08:02:57.281: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
(process:4308): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:02:57.281: g_variant_get: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
window_title: (null)
success: 21986 // (garbage value)
If you use the comand line tool, you can see that the Eval method works:
$ gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "global.get_window_actors().find(actor => actor.meta_window  .has_focus()).meta_window.get_title()"
(true, '"ibse@ibse-VirtualBox: ~"')
I need to get the same data (in this case true, '"ibse@ibse-VirtualBox: ~"), but using c glib api

Maybe try gboolean success; gchar *window_title; g_variant_get(result, "(bs)", &success, &window_title);

I did this. I check the contents of success and window_title using printf(): printf("%s\n%d\n", window_title, success); Result:
(null)
22062
The value of success changes from launch to launch, that is, there is some kind of garbage value there
g_printf shows the same thing
Also after adding g_variant_get it is printed: (process:4172): GLib-CRITICAL **: 07:50:08.892: g_variant_get: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
And even before this, 2 CRITICAL were published, I’ll update the post now @BillMorgan

try removing the trailing slash from the path: "/org/gnome/Shell",

yes, it helped and I also needed to take s from g_variant_new into brackets: g_variant_new("(s)", "global.get... @BillMorgan
